# Can I get away with just doing pull-ups for lats?

Tags: weightlifting, pull-ups

I really hate all the other lat exercises - I find them boring and unsatisfying. Are pull-ups enough to work all the back muscles or am I really missing something if I only do these?

Add to this also the fact that I don't really like that look of massive flaring lats that give you a V shape. - and I also do quite high resistance rowing (on a machine though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing deadlifts for the spinal erectors, then using pullups/chinups for your upper back work is sufficient. (I mention deadlifts, because pull-ups/chin-ups neglect the lower back.)

Starting Strength, a very popular full body strength training program uses pull-ups/chin-ups for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

"Get away with"? From whom are you attempting to escape?

Lats aren't the only back muscle, of course, although normal core work will target others.

Ultimately it depends 100% on your goals. There aren't any workout police you need to fool.

Comment: Your first line would have made sense if I'd said "get way from" somewhere in what I wrote. This doesn't answer my question of 'are there any back muscle groups that would be neglected if I just did rowing and pull ups'.

Comment: @SirYakalot You're right--I assume people have a sense of humor, which is often wrong. With that in mind, this question is trivially searchable, and I did indicate that there are other muscle groups besides lats, which is "yes", there are. Also, without knowing your goals, other than not having a V-taper, it's more difficult to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Make the DB or BB Pullovers your best friend.  Try different variations either bent-arm or straight arm to really work on the ribcage and those lats.  If you do this consistently for a year, increase the reps/weights/etc come back to this forum and tell me what the result was for achieving lat strength or that V-taper :-) (I know you mentioned you don't like a massive V-taper but this is an excellent exercise for your lats and for your body --> see it basically as a reverse C yoga stretch with weight)